# Data on business locations

Tags: data-request, geospatial, business

I am working on an app for the iPhone right now. It involves using location data of local businesses. I was wondering if it would be better to either create a web crawler or buy the data from somewhere? I was looking around and the only place to buy data I could find is infochimps.com is there any other places to buy data from?

Comment: I'm closing this question because you explicitly ask where you can buy data. This site is about open data — which, by definition, should be free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't comment so sharing advice in an answer: Can you be more specific about what type of location data?

- If every type of category, you're probably best using APIs/licensed data from the likes of Infochimps, Google Places, Yelp, Foursquare, etc.
- If you're doing something smaller scope like hospitals and clinics or maybe gas stations, you can probably find some open data about it that covers the majority of the data points and ultimately saves you money.

Comment: yeh its every type of category.  Money isn't too much of a problem so is there a good place to buy the data?  If not I guess we'll just have to use APIs

Comment: Then I would go to infochimps as they seem to expect you to store the data. Four square and others, if I recall correctly, only want you to look up using their API when needed and not store locally. Maybe also look at yellowpages

Answer (score 4):

Foursquare provides a location layer, check it out.
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues

Answer (score 3):

[Wikimapia](http://wikimapia.org/) has plenty of business locations datasets. And as I know, they have an API to use.

Here is the website of the [Wikimapia API](http://wikimapia.org/api#placegetbyarea) and here is an [example](http://api.wikimapia.org/?key=example&function=place.getbyarea&coordsby=bbox&bbox=2.292493,48.8590143,2.293493,48.8599143) of the output when you search by a specific area.

Comment: Does each item has a type? For instance how can you differentiate between a restaurant and a hotel?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul You are right. I was from mobile and I could add a lot of info. I have updated the answer with the API page and an output example. As for your question, yes there is a tag"category" which provides info about the type of the item.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikivoyage](http://wikivoyage.org/) has business details for the whole world. Its goal is not to cover ALL businesses, but to cover the best restaurants/hotels/attractions in 3 range of prices (yes it is subjective).

The whole data is available as CSV here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wikivoyage/files/Listings-as-CSV/

Free, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License.

Sample:

```
TITLE;TYPE;NAME;ALT;ADDRESS;DIRECTIONS;PHONE;TOLLFREE;EMAIL;FAX;URL;HOURS;CHECKIN;CHECKOUT;IMAGE;PRICE;LAT;LON;CONTENT
"Tokyo/Roppongi";"sleep";"Hotel Villa Fontaine Roppongi";"";"Roppongi 1-6-2 Izumi Garden";"direct connection to Roppongi Itchome station (Namboku line)";"+81 3 3560-1110";"";"";"+81 3 3560-1388";"http://www.hvf.jp/roppongi/";"";"15:00";"11:00";"";"From ¥10,000 per night (with great weekend specials from ¥6300)";"35.66418";"139.73954";"Nice and spacious rooms targeting business travelers."
```