# Dataset of retail (chain) store locations by store number

Tags: data-request, geospatial, business, companies

I'm looking for a dataset which translates US store name and numbers to (geo) locations or street addresses.

For example:

```
Chick-Fil-A #2193 is located at 1845 Main St, Chester, MD 21619.
Panda Express #2529 is located at 4506 N Main St, Roswell, NM 88201.
Wendy's #5218 is located at 13430 W Maple Rd, Omaha, NE 68164.
Chipotle #1720 is located at 865 Market Street, Space C10, San Francisco, CA 94103.
J. Crew #508 is located at 3222 M St NW, Washington DC, 20007.
Nordstrom #736 is located at 9607 Research Boulevard, Austin, TX 78759.
```

It looks like there are a couple of (spammy) websites which try to do something similar, e.g. `storelocations411.com` and `chargeprotect.com` (not hyperlinked to avoid more link spam).

I'm surprised that there's nothing obvious out there, so I'm hoping I missed something - any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean with "number"? Ordered by what?

Comment: Good point, @phillbaker these does not look like UIDs (unique identifiers).

Comment: @RoyalTS many large chains identify each location by a number - these numbers are determined by the companies themselves and may be unique per region or globally. I gave a few examples in the question.

Comment: Ah, it looks like Foursquare may have some of this data as answered here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3241/15889.  `storeId` in the venue response (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue) might work.